# Power Automate Flow that retrieves the name of a column in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, powershell, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I'm creating a flow that alerts users whenever they have an expired certification inside a SharePoint list.  When it comes to the part where I need to send the email to let the user know I can't find a way to notify the user which certification of the SharePoint list is expired because the certification names are posing as columns names in the list and I can't find a function to extract and express the column name in the email (not the values in the column)

EX:

Hi (user name) the cert (cert name I don't know how to obtain) is expired please follow this url to comply with the requirements.

v/r,

Matthew

Comment: Is there any column like Status where you are maintaining the expired certifications or any due date ?

Comment: You can create a variable at the start of flow and where you are checking if certification is expired using date/calculated column, you can set the variable value with the name of certification (hard coded). Then use this variable while sending an email notification.

Comment: You can also get the list columns using API call (Send HTTP request to SharePoint action): `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false`. More details at: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-get-columns-name-from-sharepoint-list/m-p/1645887/highlight/true#M419625

Comment: Hi @Saira yes, I have 7 different columns because the flow needs to target 7 different certifications.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap this would work if I only had one certification but I have 7 certifications that needs to be verified by a condition.

Comment: @GaneshSanap the second link has important information, thanks

Comment: Are you adding only one condition for all 7 certifications? If you are adding 7 different conditions, you can add set variable action in respective condition "If yes" block & update variable with certification/column name. Let me know if this approach or approach given in above link works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have 7 conditions for every user because there are 7 certifications. The problem is that I need to determine which certification is expired and include it in the email with the name.

Comment: Does each of those 7 certifications have 7 different columns as Due Date or Expired Date ?